# TextView in Android Studio not showing

Tags: java, android

While using linear layout, just the text in the first TextView, which is "Hey I am new here", is displayed. How can i show also "Claim your prize!" and "Clicca qui"?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:text="Hey I am new here"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/prize_id"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:lines="2"
    android:text="Claim your prize!"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/buttonid"
    android:text="Clicca qui"
    android:onClick="prize claimed"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show in vertical stack
use `android:orientation="vertical"` instead of `android:orientation="horizontal"` for `LinearLayout`.

If you want to show in horizontal stack give `weight` to each `TextView`.

Answer (score 3):

Change the

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

to

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your parent `layout` `orientation` `android:orientation="horizontal"` to `android:orientation="vertical"`

Answer (score 1):

you can do this in this way if you want to show them horizontally ::

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="Hey I am new here"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/prize_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:lines="2"
        android:text="Claim your prize!"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonid"
        android:text="Clicca qui"
        android:onClick="prize claimed"  />

</LinearLayout>
```